# iOS Simulator not displaying app

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I'm getting this outlet message in the debugger when I go to start my application: "2014-07-17 23:52:13.449 Journey[59668:60b] The app delegate must implement the window property if it wants to use a main storyboard file." But I'm not getting any errors or warnings? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you include the following line of code in your App Delegate header file.

`@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;`

Comment: Thanks, I'll add it now, I remember deleting it and thinking I needed to add it back but I never did. I'll try now.